# How do i count the number of items in a table and join with categories from different table in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select count distinct items from Table 2 and match it to the category list in Table 1. This is a MySQL database sample.

Table 1 (categories):

```
id   group_name
1      football
2      hockey
3      tennis
```

Table 2 (users):

```
id   groups
1      tennis
2      football
3      football
4      tennis
5      football
6      hockey
7      hockey
```

Answer (score 0):

The below SQL query would do it:

```
SELECT A.GROUP_NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT GROUPS) CNTS 
FROM CATEGORIES A
LEFT JOIN USERS B
ON A.GROUP_NAME = B.GROUPS
```